# filtering single matrix conditional upon column name regex AND element value

Tags: python, r, pandas, matrix

This is a question rooted in trying to filter one matrix. The input file type is a .txt file containing sample names as columns, unique (sequence) identifiers as rows/index, and elements of the matrix are counts of sequences observed for a given sample. If your familiar with amplicon sequencing (16-S microbiomes, ITS fungal/plant, etc.), yes, this is an OTU table, but if you haven't, it doesn't matter, I swear! Please note I can control the names of the columns of the input file so feel free to suggest a better naming convention if you see fit. I point this out only because it's my understanding that packages like Pandas have the capacity to retain multi-level naming conventions; please remember the input file is just a text file to start, so I can only 'rename' my input file with delimiters should they prove useful in downstream filtering.

I've created an example dataset in R and Python, so feel free to use the either to recreate. Apologies for not naming the R and Python file the same, but I wanted to make it easier for answers to differentiate whether you took the Python or R approach.

```
## Python enthusiasts:
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
[[1,2,0,0,0,0], [3,0,4,0,0,0], [0,0,5,6,7,0], [0,0,8,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,99]], 
columns=['s1-G1', 's2-G1', 's3-G2', 's4-G2', 's5-G3', 's6-G3'],
index=['OTU1', 'OTU2', 'OTU3', 'OTU4', 'OTU5'])

## R enthusiasts:

ra <- c(1,2,0,0,0,0)
rb <- c(3,0,4,0,0,0)
rc <- c(0,0,5,6,7,0)
rd <- c(0,0,8,0,0,0)
re <- c(0,0,0,0,0,99)
mat <- rbind(ra,rb,rc,rd,re)

colnames(mat) <- c("s1-G1", "s2-G1", "s3-G2", "s4-G2", "s5-G3", "s6-G3")

rownames(mat) <- c("OTU1", "OTU2", "OTU3", "OTU4", "OTU5")
```

Hopefully you get a data set that looks like this:

```
     s1-G1 s2-G1 s3-G2 s4-G2 s5-G3 s6-G3
OTU1     1     2     0     0     0     0
OTU2     3     0     4     0     0     0
OTU3     0     0     5     6     7     0
OTU4     0     0     8     0     0     0
OTU5     0     0     0     0     0     99
```

As you might have guessed, the column names actually specify two levels or organization, despite being concatenated together: a sample name, and a group name. Thus `s1-G1`, `s2-G1`, represent distinct samples from the ***same*** group, while `s1-G1` and `s3-G2` represent distinct samples from ***different*** groups. I point this out because the filtering goals require some sort of expression to group by the `G#` portion of the name, while the `S#` portion isn't relevant for this question.

Alright, so what's the goal? The goal is to filter this dataset such that we split this matrix into two new matricies: one called `df_uniq` and another called `df_dupd`. The specifics for each new matrix:

I want to filter the **rows**, such that any row in the `df_uniq` matrix is included when we observe one or more matrix elements with a value greater than zero for any number columns EXCEPT all of those matches are contained within only one *unique* `G` value. In the example matrix above, this would result in a new `df_uniq` matrix that looked like this:

```
     s1-G1 s2-G1 s3-G2 s4-G2 s5-G3 s6-G3
OTU1     1     2     0     0     0     0
OTU4     0     0     8     0     0     0
OTU5     0     0     0     0     0     99
```

because we observe values greater than zero in columns `s1-G1` and `s3-G2` for row **OTU2** (which are in two independent groups `G1` and `G2`), those aren't included in the resulting matrix; likewise row **OTU3** is also excluded for the same reason (it contains more than one non-zero value in two groups, `G2` and `G3`).

The other matrix, `df_dupd` would contain the opposite of what's in `df_uniq` - any row in which there is at least one non-zero element in the matrix for which there are **at least two unique `G` samples observed. The values from the initial matrix would produce a new table containing what we didn't include in our `df_uniq` table:

```
     s1-G1 s2-G1 s3-G2 s4-G2 s5-G3 s6-G3
OTU2     3     0     4     0     0     0
OTU3     0     0     5     6     7     0
```

Thank you for your consideration and support. I look forward to your responses.

Devon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following example using data.table should get you started:

```
library(data.table)

ra <- c(1,2,0,0,0,0)
rb <- c(3,0,4,0,0,0)
rc <- c(0,0,5,6,7,0)
rd <- c(0,0,8,0,0,0)
re <- c(0,0,0,0,0,99)
mat <- rbind(ra,rb,rc,rd,re)

colnames(mat) <- c("s1-G1", "s2-G1", "s3-G2", "s4-G2", "s5-G3", "s6-G3")
rownames(mat) <- c("OTU1", "OTU2", "OTU3", "OTU4", "OTU5")

# Convert to data.table

dat.wide <- data.table(mat)

# add back in OTU as column
dat.wide[, OTU := c("OTU1", "OTU2", "OTU3", "OTU4", "OTU5")]

# Convert to long format
dat.long <- melt(dat.wide)

# split sample and group name into separate columns, creating new column "value"
dat.long[, c("sample","group") := tstrsplit(variable, split="-")]

# remove original joint sample-group column
dat.long[, variable := NULL]

# get unique OTUs
unique.OTUs <- dat.long[, list(N=sum(value)), by=list(group, OTU)][, list(Ngroups=sum(N>0)), by=OTU][Ngroups==1]$OTU

dat.wide[OTU %in% unique.OTUs]

# output:
# s1-G1 s2-G1 s3-G2 s4-G2 s5-G3 s6-G3  OTU
#     1     2     0     0     0     0 OTU1
#     0     0     8     0     0     0 OTU4
#     0     0     0     0     0    99 OTU5

dat.wide[! (OTU %in% unique.OTUs)]

# output:
# s1-G1 s2-G1 s3-G2 s4-G2 s5-G3 s6-G3  OTU
#     3     0     4     0     0     0 OTU2
#     0     0     5     6     7     0 OTU3
```

In greater detail: Long format table looks like

```
 OTU value sample group
OTU1     1     s1    G1
OTU2     3     s1    G1
OTU3     0     s1    G1
OTU4     0     s1    G1
OTU5     0     s1    G1
OTU1     2     s2    G1
OTU2     0     s2    G1
OTU3     0     s2    G1
OTU4     0     s2    G1
OTU5     0     s2    G1
OTU1     0     s3    G2
OTU2     4     s3    G2
OTU3     5     s3    G2
OTU4     8     s3    G2
OTU5     0     s3    G2
OTU1     0     s4    G2
OTU2     0     s4    G2
OTU3     6     s4    G2
OTU4     0     s4    G2
OTU5     0     s4    G2
OTU1     0     s5    G3
OTU2     0     s5    G3
OTU3     7     s5    G3
OTU4     0     s5    G3
OTU5     0     s5    G3
OTU1     0     s6    G3
OTU2     0     s6    G3
OTU3     0     s6    G3
OTU4     0     s6    G3
OTU5    99     s6    G3
```

Which allows us to first sum the observations for each group/OTU combo:

```
step1 <- dat.long[, list(N=sum(value)), by=list(group, OTU)]
```

giving us

```
group  OTU  N
   G1 OTU1  3
   G1 OTU2  3
   G1 OTU3  0
   G1 OTU4  0
   G1 OTU5  0
   G2 OTU1  0
   G2 OTU2  4
   G2 OTU3 11
   G2 OTU4  8
   G2 OTU5  0
   G3 OTU1  0
   G3 OTU2  0
   G3 OTU3  7
   G3 OTU4  0
   G3 OTU5 99
```

chain on [, list(Ngroups=sum(N>0)), by=OTU] to count the number of groups with nonzero observations

```
step2 <- step1[, list(Ngroups=sum(N>0)), by=OTU]
```

giving us

```
 OTU Ngroups
OTU1       1
OTU2       2
OTU3       2
OTU4       1
OTU5       1
```

lastly chain on [Ngroups==1] to select rows where nonzero observations only occur in on group

```
step3 <- step2[Ngroups==1]
step3
```

giving us

```
 OTU Ngroups
OTU1       1
OTU4       1
OTU5       1
```

Lastly, filter the original wide data.table based on the unique OTUs as we did above.

Comment: Thanks very much @caw5cv.  

Because I will ultimately have a matrix with many more than five rows, I'd tweak the line where rather than typing in all the row names again, I'd just make a list:  

`# add back in OTU as column`
`myrownames <- rownames(mat)`
`dat.wide[, OTU := myrownames]`

Works like a charm on the test dataset. Let's see how data.table handles a 3,000 x 20,000 dataset.